# how to avoid the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
import torchaudio
def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
    speech_array, sampling_rate = torchaudio.load(batch["key"])
    batch["speech"] = speech_array[0].numpy()
    batch["sampling_rate"] = sampling_rate
    batch["target_text"] = batch["text"]
    return batch

train_set = data.map(speech_file_to_array_fn, remove_columns=data.column_names)
test_set = test_data.map(speech_file_to_array_fn, remove_columns=test_data.column_names)
```

I am running this code but facing the error :

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

I tried multiple versions of pandas but still facing the same issue.

Comment: [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) only exists as of 2.1.0, prior to that you need [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)